# Synchronous form submit to Asynchronous submit - Issue

Tags: jquery, jsp, asynchronous, synchronous

I have a button on UI which adds messages and when the user clicks on it the form gets submitted, meanwhile the user is clicking on refresh(F5) multiple times which is causing the same message to be displayed multiple times. To resolve this , I am converting the form from a synchronous submit to Asychronous but it is still not working. Please assist. Below is the code:

Code before:

```
<td><input class="buttonred" type="submit" value="Confirm Add" name="submit_message"></td>

<s:form action="upd-message" method="POST" validate="true" onsubmit="validateMsg();return false;" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Code After:

```
<tr>
                                <td width="15%"><strong>Subject:</strong></td>                                                               
                                <td width="30%" class="contentformnoline">
                                    <input name="subject" size="12" maxlength="100">                              
                                </td>
                                <td width="20%">&nbsp;</td>                                                               
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td><strong>Message:</strong></td>                                                               
                                <td class="contentformnoline">
                                    <textarea cols="65" rows="3" name="content" wrap="hard"></textarea>                                 
                                </td>
                                <td>&nbsp;</td>                                                               
                            </tr>
```

```
<div id="loading_reloadpage" style="display:none;">
                            <tagfile:loading id="loading_reloadpage_img" size="11px"/>&nbsp;Reloading information...
                        </div>

<tr id="test-sc-step2-errors-row" style="display:none">
                        <td></td>
                        <td colspan="2" class="contentform" height="30"><span id="newSR-sc-step2-errors" class="alert"></span></td>
                    </tr>
```

In my jquery.js

```
 jQuery.submitMessage= function() {
    incidentsInspect.submitMessage = function() {
    var bError = true;
    var subject = $('#subject');
    alert("subject"+$('#subject'));

    var content = $('#content');
    alert("content"+$('#content'));
    if (this.isEmpty(subject)) {
        $('#test-sc-step2-errors-row').html('Please enter a subject.');
    }
    else if (this.isEmpty(content)) {
        $('#test-sc-step2-errors-row').html('Please enter a content.');
    } 
    else {
        bError = false;
    }

    if (bError) {
        $('#test-sc-step2-errors-row').show();
    } else {
        //$('#loading_reloadpage').show();
        //$('#loading_reloadpage_img').show();
        show("loading_reloadpage");
        show("loading_reloadpage_img");

        var dataToPost = {
                actionType : $('#actionType').val()
            };

        var url = '/portal/tickets/update-incident.action';
        $.post(url, dataToPost,
                function(data) {

        }
        ).error(incidentsInspect.handleError);
    }
};
```

Things which are not working:

1. When I do browser refresh, it still does multiple submits and adds the messages multiple times.
2. Validations not working, I added alerts to print the values but it displays the value as object.
3. show("loading_reloadpage");
   show("loading_reloadpage_img"); not working

Please assist.

Comment: I don't see how that will have any effect on F5 causing the form to submit again.

Comment: because the URL doesnt change and clicking F5 causes multiple submits

Comment: clicking F5? or clicking the submit button.

Comment: once the form is submitted, the URL doesnt change and when the user clicks F5 the form gets submitted again and again

Comment: Again i ask... What do you mean by click F5? F5 is a key on your keyboard, you can't click it... If you mean pressing F5, then there's nothing you can do with javascript to prevent that. you need to perform server-side redirect.

Comment: The user is doing a refresh on the browser, I tried redirectAction but redirecting to the same page is giving issues. Hence I am trying to convert the form to asynchronous submit so that even if the user clicks refresh it only refreshes that portion of the message section.

Comment: What you are doing isn't asynchronous at all though. To make that change, you would need to change to using ajax.

Answer (score 0):

In your JSP/Servlet that handles/processes the submit, do this at the end:

```
response.sendRedirect("someotherpage");
return;
```

Since this redirect takes place server-side, it will result in the processing page not being stored in the browser history, so it will be impossible to get to it by the back-button, and since you can't get to it, you can't hit refresh on it.

But I should also point out: There is nothing Asynchronous about your submit at all.

Comment: I cannot use a redirect to another page as I need to stay on the same page, I have modified the code above to submit using ajax jquery. Please help.

Comment: so, redirect to the same page.